# Multithreading with AsyncTask(): using wait() and notify()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, wait, notify

I am having hard time to understand how multitasking works in Java. I read some articles here on SO but still have problems.

I have my Main class, in which I execute AsyncTask, and I would like to stop code execution of main class until the AsyncTask is finished. In AsyncTask I gather data from internet. I would like to gather data, get the result, and notify in onPostExecute() method. Here is simplified code:

```
public class MainClass extends Activity  {

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            //(...Some calcuations here)

            synchronized (self) {
                self.notify();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView.setText(result);
            //I would like to notify here, but it is not working
        }
    }

    private void callAsyncTask()
    {
        myTask = (MyTask) new MyTask().execute(someString, someOtherString);

        synchronized (self) 
        {
            try 
            {
                self.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    //(...)Some code where I callAsyncTask()

}
```

Is my understanding of using wait() and notify() correct? Can someone explain me what should I be aware of while using those methods?

Comment: If you're trying to stop execution of the main thread, you're really defeating the purpose of multithreading. You might as well just run it on the main thread.

Comment: I think I couldn't, because gathering data from internet requires separate Thread.

Comment: Why? If you're trying to block the main class, then just run it on the main thread. Otherwise if you want it to be a background task, then run it on a separate thread but don't block the main. Rather just do something with the data when the background thread is finished.

Comment: When I try to get data from internet on main thread, I get "NetworkOnMainThreadException". I need to create separate Thread to get data from internet, but I don't want my Main Thread code to execute until I finish downloading the data...

Comment: Yes, you are correct, sorry about that, but I still don't think you should be blocking the main thread - that's why they have that error there in the first place. You should reconsider your design so you don't have to block the main thread (I know this doesn't answer your question, but I don't think you should be doing what you're doing if you can avoid it).

Comment: Here is something that I could do, but it is also not working (new topic) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204309/asynctask-get-method-not-working-properly Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

just use get() after execute() when you wanna execute the Asynctask

```
       MyTask mytask=new MyTask (); 
       mytask.execute("arg").get();
```