# AsyncTask get() method not working properly

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am using the following code:

```
//(...)
translationTextView.setText("Searching for translation...");
translationTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

myAsyncTask = (MyAsyncTask) new MyAsyncTask().execute(someString);

try {
    //As I understand it should wait here until AsyncTask is completed. But why for the time of execution translateTextView value is ""?
    translationTextView.setText(translateTask.get() + "<BR>");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that `translationTextView` value is "" until `myAsyncTask` is finished. So it looks like

```
translationTextView.setText("Searching for translation...");
```

is not called. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I assume it's just a typo in your question but you're initialising "myAsyncTask" but calling get on "translateTask". Either way you shouldn't be calling get on the main UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

It is called but then you call

```
translationTextView.setText(translateTask.get() + "<BR>");
```

and `get()` is a blocking call

Try instead to set the text in your `onPostExecute()`. If I understand you correctly then something like this should give you what you want

```
   //(...)
        translationTextView.setText("Searching for translation...");
        translationTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        myAsyncTask = (MyAsyncTask) new MyAsyncTask().execute(someString);
```

Then, assuming `MyAsyncTask` is an inner class of your `Activity` call `translationTextView.setText()` inserting whatever you are trying to return from `doInBackground()`

Comment: But why the code is not executed before calling get() method? How can I make it work?

Comment: Try my updated answer. Also, you could put a breakpoint in there to see what exactly is executed. A progress dialog may be better so the user sees something moving and doesn't think your app is frozen...its a mental thing with users

Comment: This is exactly what I did before. My task is translating text online. but after this I also translate it offline. I would like to wait for online translation to complete before calling offline translation. Until now, I was calling offline translation in onPostExecute method, but I think it is not good approach, considering my Task name is onlineTranslation...I would like that task to do only online translation and after it is finished call offline translation from main Thread...

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand (why two translations and which is this) but either way you should be setting the text in `onPostExecute()` or call a function from there that does something else

Comment: So it is not possible to set the text of my TextView to "Searching for translation..." before calling AsyncTask?

Comment: It certainly is. You can do that in `onPreExecute()` or how you are now but you need to take out the call with `get()`

Answer (score 1):

As codeMagic points out, override the `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask` subclass, if you haven't already. It's executed on the main thread, you should update your UI there.