# Why is my UI only shown when AsyncTask has finished?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I put a sub class called `RetrieveHttp` extending `AsycTask` in my `MainActivity` which should do some processing stuff in background.

The Activity should work as follows: 
Showing the UI, starting background tasks (retrieving URL, parsing stuff to a String array) and when AsyncTask has finished it should create a Toast on the UI.

Unfortunately the UI is waiting for the task done by the `doInBackground()` method. Only when `AsyncTask` has finished, the UI is shown and the user meanwhile is just seeing a blackscreen. Could you give me some advices please, what is wrong with my code?

```
public class Splashscreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private String questions[];
//HTTP-Downloader to InputStream
private RetrieveHttp myHttp = new RetrieveHttp();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hauptmenue);

    //..implementing some listeners here, referencing GUI elements

    try {
        questions = myHttp.execute("http://myurl.de").get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hauptmenue, menu);     
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    //doing some stuff...
}

public class RetrieveHttp extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        String string = "";
        String[] questions = null;
        InputStream content = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            content = getInputStreamFromUrl(url.toString());
            try {
                // Stream to String
                string = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(
                        content, "UTF-8"));
                questions = string.split("#");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return questions;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String[] string) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

}

public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
    InputStream content = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);
    }


    return content;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AsyncTask get() method not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204309/asynctask-get-method-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 5):

because this line

`questions = myHttp.execute("http://myurl.de").get();`

the `get` method waits for the asynctask to finish essentially negating what an async task is suppose to do.

remove the get and set your `questions` in the `onPostExecute` of the asynctask and the UI will show like normal